# Android - Authenticate log in against email server

Tags: android, email, authentication, smtp

I am trying to authenticate a user's login information ( username and password ) against an email server ( smtp ).  I was using the JavaMail API to make it work in straight Java, but I guess JavaMail isn't compatible with Android.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Apache commons net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) , It supports:

- SMTP(S)
- POP3(S)
- IMAP(S)

Also has some client examples for: [IMAP](http://commons.apache.org/net/examples/mail/IMAPMail.java) , [POP3](http://commons.apache.org/net/examples/mail/POP3Mail.java) and [SMTP](http://commons.apache.org/net/examples/mail/SMTPMail.java).